# Opening a fullscreen OpenGL window

Tags: opengl, x11, nvidia, glfw

I am tring to open an OpenGL full screen window using GLFW on linux red-hat. I have a desktop that spans two monitors with total resolution of 3840*1080.

I have two problems:
1. The window is opened just on one monitor with maximum window width of 1920 (the width of a single monitor).
2. The maximum height of the window is 1003 (which I think is the height of the screen minus the height of the task bar and the top bar).

This is the code I use to open the window:

```
if (glfwInit() == GL_FALSE)
    std::cout<< "Unable to initialize GLFW\n";
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_STEREO, GL_FALSE);
if (glfwOpenWindow(3840,1080,8,8,8,0,24,0,GLFW_FULLSCREEN) == GL_FALSE)
    std::cout<< "Unable to open window\n";
int width, height;
glfwGetWindowSize(&width, &height);
std::cout << "width = " << width << " height = " << height << "\n";
```

output: width = 1920 height = 1003

EDIT:
I used xrandr to check available screen mode and got:

Screen 0: minimum 3840 x 1080, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 3840 x 1080
default connected 3840x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3840x1080      50.0*

EDIT2:
I have changed my code to open the window using X11

```
int doubleBufferAttributes[] = {
GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
GLX_RENDER_TYPE,   GLX_RGBA_BIT,
GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,  True,  /* Request a double-buffered color buffer with */
GLX_RED_SIZE,      1,     /* the maximum number of bits per component    */
GLX_GREEN_SIZE,    1, 
    GLX_BLUE_SIZE,     1,
    None
};

static Bool WaitForNotify( Display *dpy, XEvent *event, XPointer arg ) {
    return (event->type == MapNotify) && (event->xmap.window == (Window) arg);
}
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    Display              *dpy;
    Window                xWin;
    XEvent                event;
    XVisualInfo          *vInfo;
    XSetWindowAttributes  swa;
    GLXFBConfig          *fbConfigs;
    GLXContext            context;
    GLXWindow             glxWin;
    int                   swaMask;
    int                   numReturned;
    int                   swapFlag = True;

    /* Open a connection to the X server */

dpy = XOpenDisplay( NULL );
if ( dpy == NULL ) {
    printf( "Unable to open a connection to the X server\n" );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

/* Request a suitable framebuffer configuration - try for a double 
** buffered configuration first */
fbConfigs = glXChooseFBConfig( dpy, DefaultScreen(dpy),
                               doubleBufferAttributes, &numReturned );

/* Create an X colormap and window with a visual matching the first
** returned framebuffer config */
vInfo = glXGetVisualFromFBConfig( dpy, fbConfigs[0] );

swa.border_pixel = 0;
swa.event_mask = StructureNotifyMask;
swa.colormap = XCreateColormap( dpy, RootWindow(dpy, vInfo->screen),
                                vInfo->visual, AllocNone );

swaMask = CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask;

xWin = XCreateWindow( dpy, RootWindow(dpy, vInfo->screen), 0, 0, 3840, 1080,
                      0, vInfo->depth, InputOutput, vInfo->visual,
                      swaMask, &swa );
XWindowAttributes attt;

XGetWindowAttributes( dpy,xWin, &attt);
std::cout << "he = " << attt.height << " wi = " << attt.width << "\n";

/* Create a GLX context for OpenGL rendering */
context = glXCreateNewContext( dpy, fbConfigs[0], GLX_RGBA_TYPE,
             NULL, True );
XGetWindowAttributes( dpy,xWin, &attt);
std::cout << "2he = " << attt.height << " wi = " << attt.width << "\n";


/* Create a GLX window to associate the frame buffer configuration
** with the created X window */
glxWin = glXCreateWindow( dpy, fbConfigs[0], xWin, NULL );
XGetWindowAttributes( dpy,xWin, &attt);
std::cout << "3he = " << attt.height << " wi = " << attt.width << "\n";

/* Map the window to the screen, and wait for it to appear */
XMapWindow( dpy, xWin );
XGetWindowAttributes( dpy,xWin, &attt);
std::cout << "4he = " << attt.height << " wi = " << attt.width << "\n";

XIfEvent( dpy, &event, WaitForNotify, (XPointer) xWin );
XGetWindowAttributes( dpy,xWin, &attt);
std::cout << "5he = " << attt.height << " wi = " << attt.width << "\n";


/* Bind the GLX context to the Window */
glXMakeContextCurrent( dpy, glxWin, glxWin, context );
XGetWindowAttributes( dpy,xWin, &attt);
std::cout << "6he = " << attt.height << " wi = " << attt.width << "\n";
```

the output is:

```
he = 1080 wi = 3840
2he = 1080 wi = 3840
3he = 1080 wi = 3840
4he = 1080 wi = 3840
5he = 1003 wi = 1920
6he = 1003 wi = 1920
```

it seems that when the window is get displayed its size shrinks.

Comment: Have you tried enumerating the available video modes and checking what is available?

Comment: I use GLFW to open the window, so no. I used 'xrandr' to query the video mode:
Screen 0: minimum 3840 x 1080, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 3840 x 1080.

I am currently changing the code to directly opening the window using X. Can you point me to a function that enumerates available video modes?
default connected 3840x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   3840x1080      50.0*

Comment: @NicolBolas please see latest edit of the question.

Comment: If your window gets resized after creation, then your window manager thinks it knows better than you what to do. In that case I'd just change the WM or file a bug report to the WM developer(s).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't know about GLFW, perhaps it's buggy, but X11 fullscreen windows don't work like that. Any window manager worth its salt will force the window to fit the (single, non-virtual) screen.

You want to either bypass the window manager completely (use `OverrideRedirect` window attribute), or ask your WM to cooperate (use window property `_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN`). The first approach has numerous drawbacks, so let's use the second one. The following program will display a window on your display, and then toggle it to the full-screen mode:

```
#include <X11/X.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    Display* dis = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    Window win = XCreateSimpleWindow(dis, RootWindow(dis, 0), 0, 0, 10, 10,
                                     0, BlackPixel (dis, 0), BlackPixel(dis, 0));

    Atom wm_state = XInternAtom(dis, "_NET_WM_STATE", False);
    Atom fullscreen = XInternAtom(dis, "_NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN", False);

    XEvent xev;
    memset(&xev, 0, sizeof(xev));
    xev.type = ClientMessage;
    xev.xclient.window = win;
    xev.xclient.message_type = wm_state;
    xev.xclient.format = 32;
    xev.xclient.data.l[0] = 1;
    xev.xclient.data.l[1] = fullscreen;
    xev.xclient.data.l[2] = 0;

    XMapWindow(dis, win);

    XSendEvent (dis, DefaultRootWindow(dis), False,
                    SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask, &xev);

    XFlush(dis);
    /*Sleep 5 seconds before closing.*/
    sleep(5);
    return(0);

}
```

You probably to use your real screen dimensions for the window from the start, in order to avoid any resize animation effect.

I didn't try this on a multihead system because I don't have one, but on a single display system it works properly (covers the panel, removes window decorations etc). Please let me know if it works for you.

**Update** They say for multihead to work, you need to use `_NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS` property (see [here](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#id2579022)). It's an array of 4 integers that should be set like this:

```
    Atom fullmons = XInternAtom(dis, "_NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS", False);
    XEvent xev;
    memset(&xev, 0, sizeof(xev));
    xev.type = ClientMessage;
    xev.xclient.window = win;
    xev.xclient.message_type = fullmons;
    xev.xclient.format = 32;
    xev.xclient.data.l[0] = 0; /* your topmost monitor number */
    xev.xclient.data.l[1] = 0; /* bottommost */
    xev.xclient.data.l[2] = 0; /* leftmost */
    xev.xclient.data.l[3] = 1; /* rightmost */
    xev.xclient.data.l[4] = 0; /* source indication */

    XSendEvent (dis, DefaultRootWindow(dis), False,
                    SubstructureRedirectMask | SubstructureNotifyMask, &xev);
```

With this, you should be able to set your fullscreen windows to occupy a single monitor, the entire desktop, or (for more than 2 monitors) anything in between.

I have not checked this because I don't have a multihead system.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Before I saw your answer I tried using OverrideRedirect (your first suggested approach). In the end I turned on Xinerama mode in the xorg.conf (a mode that tricks the WM into thinking that there is just one big monitor).

Comment: Thanks very much, that's the only answer works for me on X11 fullscreen problem, in addition:  xev.xclient.data.l[0] = 1; can be changed to =0 for restore or =2 for toggle.

Answer (score 0):

xcb version:

```
    xcb_connection_t *xcbConnection = xcb_connect(":0", &screenp);
    xcb_intern_atom_cookie_t type = xcb_intern_atom(xcbConnection, false, strlen("_NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS"), "_NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS");
    xcb_intern_atom_reply_t *reply_st = xcb_intern_atom_reply(xcbConnection, type, NULL);

    xcb_client_message_event_t event;
    memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    event.response_type = XCB_CLIENT_MESSAGE;
    event.type = reply_st->atom;
    event.window =  this->winId();
    event.format = 32;
    event.data.data32[0] =  0; // top
    event.data.data32[1] =  0; // bottom
    event.data.data32[2] =  0; // left
    event.data.data32[3] =  1; // right

    event.data.data32[4] = 1;
    uint32_t eventMask = XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_REDIRECT|XCB_EVENT_MASK_SUBSTRUCTURE_NOTIFY;
    xcb_send_event(xcbConnection, false, pScreen0->root, eventMask, reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&event));
    xcb_flush(xcbConnection);
```