# How to display an image without decorations

Tags: imagemagick

Can't find an option for Imagemagick's `display` command to avoid decorations. Just need to show the image, is there any way to achieve this, or any other "core" command that can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean to display images without *window* decorations. There's many many ways to achieve this, but I would like to point-out that your OS/desktop-manager probably has something that you can leverage.

For example, on my mac, I can use `open` & `qlmanage` to show images with minimal decorations.

```sh
# Use OS defaults
open wizard.png
# or Quicklook
qlmanage -p wizard.png
```

[image: qlmanage]

YMMV. There's also great alternatives listed [to this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/35333).

ImageMagick's `display` utility has the options `-immutable`, `-backdrop`, & `-window` options to interact with X11 display system. If you don't mind X11's tile bar, then `-immutable` will hide the additional display widgets.

```
display -immutable -resize 40% wizard.png
```

[image: immutable]

However, if you absolutely do not want any window decoration, then you may need to role your own solution. The `-window` option will set the image as a background to a running window. Knowning this, I just need to create a borderless-window & capture an ID to pass to `identify`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31362328/438117) for creating a window w/o any decoration.

```c
// simple_window (compile with `gcc -L/usr/X11R6/lib -lX11 -o simple_window simple_window.c')
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Display * root;
    Window win;
    int screen;
    root = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    screen = DefaultScreen(root);
    win = XCreateSimpleWindow(root,
                              RootWindow(root, screen),
                              10, 10,
                              400, 600,
                              0,
                              BlackPixel(root, screen),
                              WhitePixel(root, screen));
    Atom win_type = XInternAtom(root, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE", False);
    long value = XInternAtom(root, "_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK", False);
    XChangeProperty(root,
                    win,
                    win_type,
                    4, 32,
                    PropModeReplace,
                    (unsigned char *) &value, 1);
    XMapWindow(root, win);
    printf("Window created %lu\n", win);
    XEvent e;
    while(1) {
        XNextEvent(root, &e);
        if (e.type == KeyPress) {
            break;
        }
    }
    XCloseDisplay(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling the above program & running will print out the current window id; which, I can now pass the `import` utility to write the image as a background.

[image: no decorations]

A bit hack-ish, but again, YMMV.

Comment: Simply brilliant!

Comment: Nice answer - works well. I needed to add `-I /opt/X11/include` to the compilation command on my iMac with XQuartz btw.