# Opening an image with no interface from shell(MAC OS)

Tags: image, macos, shell, media

I need to be able to open an image from my shell, with no interface and where I want on my screen. I'm sure there is existing software that would allow me to do this, any recommendations?

Comment: You should be able to use like `open exampleImage.jpg` . Peek: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/299900/how-to-open-an-image-file-from-bash-in-mac

Comment: Well, that is indeed what I'm looking at. My issue is finding an Application that would open my image Completely interfaceless, with just the image, no borders. With your example it would be Preview but without the top part.

Comment: What do you mean *"with no interface, no borders"*? What's the point of this please?

Comment: The use of it is filming the computer screen and having a green screen at a location on the screen where I can add what I need later on in After Effects. The idea would be someone launching an interface in shell that then opens that green screen. I tried doing it with VLC's dummy interface but that doesn't seem to be supported on macOS. Preview has the top part of it that I'd want removed.

Comment: I think Eric has the answer for you here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/41228386/2836621