# Can I use _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK EWHM extension in openbox?

Tags: python, xlib, ewmh, openbox

Openbox is stated to be EWMH compliant [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openbox). I want to use this compliance layer to implement a decoration-less window, as proposed [on this question's best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31002962/create-window-without-title-bar/31008189#31008189).

As such, I am trying to build a simple window using python and Xlib that uses the _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK type hint to get rid of the window decorations. But the process fails with the following code :

```
from Xlib import X, display
d = display.Display()
s = d.screen()
w = s.root.create_window(10, 10, 100, 100, 1, s.root_depth, background_pixel=s.black_pixel, event_mask=X.ExposureMask|X.KeyPressMask)
int_atom = d.intern_atom('int')
wm_window_type = d.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE')
wm_window_type_dock = d.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK')
w.change_property(wm_window_type, int_atom, 32, [wm_window_type_dock, ], X.PropModeReplace)
w.map()
d.next_event()
d.next_event()

print(w.get_full_property(wm_window_type, X.AnyPropertyType).value[0])
print(wm_window_type_dock)
```

The window shows up but still has decorations. The two last print statements both return `434`, so I guess the window does have a valid EWMH window_type.
So the question is twofold:

- Is my code valid for the purpose ?
- Should openbox draw a decoration-less window ? (And why doesn't it ?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it took me some 12 hours to find the answer :

I was using the wrong atom in `change_property`. The call should have read :

```
w.change_property(wm_window_type, Xatom.ATOM, 32, [wm_window_type_dock, ], X.PropModeReplace)
```

So, with the relevant `import` statement, the whole code becomes :

```
from Xlib import X, Xatom, display
d = display.Display()
s = d.screen()
w = s.root.create_window(10, 10, 100, 100, 1, s.root_depth, background_pixel=s.black_pixel, event_mask=X.ExposureMask|X.KeyPressMask)
wm_window_type = d.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE')
wm_window_type_dock = d.intern_atom('_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK')
w.change_property(wm_window_type, Xatom.ATOM, 32, [wm_window_type_dock, ], X.PropModeReplace)
w.map()
d.next_event()
d.next_event()
print(w.get_full_property(wm_window_type, Xatom.ATOM).value[0])
print(wm_window_type_dock)
```

Which works as expected (note that if your screen's background is black, you should change the background_pixel value to see anything at all).